# source /etc/profile is not working in my bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script to write proxy into `/etc/profile` and source it.
This is the snippet of the script

```
#!/bin/bash
configureEnv(){
        cat >> /etc/profile <<EOF
export SOCKS_SERVER=http://proxy.mycompany.com:1080
export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.mycompany.com:911
EOF
        source /etc/profile
}
configureEnv
```

I run this script on the terminal with command `./test.sh`
The proxies are added into `/etc/profile` but when i run `env | grep proxy`, there is nothing until i run `source /etc/profile` on the terminal. My terminal is using `-sh`

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Running your script won't update your environment. A running script updates *its* environment. You need to *source* the script. Why do you think *running* `/etc/profile` doesn't work?

Comment: @n.m. What do you means "running" `/etc/profile`? Any solutions I can improve my script because after this function, my script will download somethings outside the firewall, and I need the proxy take place

Comment: I don't know how to explain "running" in simple words. Execute as a separate process? You are running your own script so you should probably have a rough idea of what running is. If you have a question about downloading things with your script, you better ask a question about downloading things with your script, because it's **not** the same question as the question about getting proxy variables in your environment.

Comment: "*there is nothing until i run source /etc/profile on the terminal*" - correct.  That's how shell processes work, and that's how they are meant to work.  When you do a `source` inside another script you only change that child process's environment, it does not, and cannot, change the parent.